# Why does my turn signals intermittently flash fast?

Tags: turn-signal

Both my turn signals will, what appears randomly, flash faster then return to normal. They can repeat this cycle any number of times or not at all. I asked my husband to to check all the lights and he said they all looked fine/worked. So I don'think it's a bad bulb. I want to say that I notice this more idling at a stop light and it's really hot or really cold outside (either 90 degrees F or 32 degrees F).

What could be causing this?

Comment: Have you checked the vehicle manual to see whether the behavior is caused by the detection of a fault?

Comment: You say it's hot, 90 degrees, soooo vehicle temperature could be higher... but it's unlikely its a short circuit of any kind.... I would check with manufacturer... Although it doesnt seem like a problem that could cause any harm..

Comment: @TheJavaCoder16 yes, hot. It is only a problem so far as it is extremely annoying!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is symptomatic of a loose or poor earth on the lamps. It may be either the front or the rear earthing point. The other item to consider is the indicator/hazard unit, it may be starting to fail.

Comment: In some cars, it's also a sign that one of your bulbs are dead or starting to go.

Comment: Indeed. Turn on all of your lights, as well as the 4-way blinkers and walk around your car to see which is dead.

Comment: @JuannStrauss Rapid blinking would only indicate a broken bulb if the rapid blinking were constant. Intermittently rapid blinking is, as this answerer suggests, a sign of a ground issue.